# Avoid Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'X'

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm migrating JavaScript project to TypeScript.
Using a node module in TS such as [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) is causing some trouble for me:

```
import nodeUrl = require('url');
// ...
// this worked fine in JS 
nodeUrl.format({
     // just for demonstration
     x: this.getX(someObj),
     y: this.getY(someObj)
});
```

Results in:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'

This is due to the definition of that module function.  **From @types/node/index.d.ts**:

```
declare module "url" {
    export interface Url {
        href?: string;
        protocol?: string;
        auth?: string;
        hostname?: string;
        port?: string;
        host?: string;
        pathname?: string;
        search?: string;
        query?: string | any;
        slashes?: boolean;
        hash?: string;
        path?: string;
    }

    export function parse(urlStr: string, parseQueryString?: boolean, slashesDenoteHost?: boolean): Url;
    export function format(url: Url): string;
    export function resolve(from: string, to: string): string;
}
```

My question is how do you avoid/fix this error **without changing the declaration file**?

Comment: What are you trying to do, make it so `format` will accept arbitrary keys? I may be able to answer this.

Comment: I want the compiler to ignore the fact that I pass a JSON object to `format` method which expects an `Url` object. Or a way to *convert* my JSON to `Url` object (depends which approach is cleaner/easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
import nodeUrl = require('url');

declare module "url" {
    export function format(url: Url): string;
    export function format(x: any, y: any): string;
    export function format(url: any): string;
}
```

More info about this can be found in [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Comment: So if I got it right, this will "override" the existing declaration?

Comment: You should not override it, but augment it. You want to keep the existing definition but to add to it

Answer (score 0):

You could use an index signature:

```
export function format(url: {[index: string]: string}): string
```

This will make it so that `format` still requires an object with string keys and values, but the key names can be anything. Of course, you can mix and match the types to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to fix it:

```
nodeUrl.format(<any> {
     // just for demonstration
     x: this.getX(someObj),
     y: this.getY(someObj)
});
```

Comment: But then you lose the type safety

Comment: I would with your approach too, anyways in my case I can accept it.

Comment: My approach says that you add signatures that fit certain types (it also needs to fit with the actual implementation of course). You should avoid using `any`, I just used it to show that you can add signatures.